# Size of a serialized complete binary tree

Tags: serialization, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm tryin to work out the size of a serialized binary tree having `N` nodes (also mentioned in [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/serialize-and-deserialize-binary-tree)). This is how I calculate the size:

If we assume the storage required to store values be `V` bits for each node, then the storage needed to store `N` nodes will be `N.V`. We also need to store `NULL` for the leaves; since there are exactly `Ceiling(N/2)` leaves in a complete tree, and assuming only one bit is enough to represent `NULL`, then an additional of `2 x Ceiling(N/2)` bits will be required. `2 x Ceiling(N/2)` translates to `N+1` as in a complete tree `N` is always an odd number.

So, `N.V + (N+1)` bit is required in total.

However, I can see that in Leetcode and some other places (e.g. [this](https://spencermortensen.com/articles/serialize-a-binary-tree-in-minimal-space/)), it's calculated as `N.V + 2N`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide feedback to the answer? I would appreciate that...

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

The two references you provided (LeetCode and blog article) deal with *arbitrary* binary trees, not necessarily *complete*. So let me first deal with arbitrary binary trees:

Although a NULL reference could be represented with one bit (e.g. with value 0), you also need to store the fact that a reference is *not* a NULL (value 1). You cannot just omit the bit, as then the next bit (belonging to a node value) could be misinterpreted as indicating a NULL reference. So you should not only count that bit for each NULL reference, but count it in for all branches.

The serialised format would for each node represent:

- The node's value ( bits)
- The fact whether or not its left child is a NULL (1 bit)
- The fact whether or not its right child is a NULL (1 bit)

#### Example:

Let  be 4

Tree to serialise:

```
            10
           /  \
          7    13
                \
                 14
```

Serialisation process (level order):

| node value | has left | has right | serialised | without spacing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | yes | yes | 1010 1 1 | 101011 |
| 7 | no | no | 0111 0 0 | 011100 |
| 13 | no | yes | 1101 0 1 | 110101 |
| 14 | no | no | 1110 0 0 | 111000 |

Complete:

```
101011011100110101111000
```

If we were only to store the 0 when there is a NULL, then we would get this:

```
101001110011010111000
    ^
```

But now the bit at the indicated position is ambiguous, because that bit could be interpreted as representing a NULL reference, but actually it is the first of  bits 0111 representing the value 7.

It is however possible to reduce the serialised string with 2 bits: the very last 2 bits will always be 0 in a tree traversal that is guaranteed to end with a leaf. This is for example the case for level-order and pre-order traversals. So then you could just omit those 2 bits.

### The case for complete binary trees

First of all about the definition of a *complete* binary tree. You write:

> in a complete tree N is always an odd number.

I suppose then your definition of a complete tree is what at Wikipedia is called a [*perfect* tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). We can however also look at (nearly) complete binary trees (and then  is not necessarily odd).

For *complete* binary trees the case is simpler, as a level order traversal of a complete binary tree will never include NULLs, i.e. there are no "gaps" in such a traversal.

So you can just serialise the node's values in that order, giving each  bits. This is actually the array representation that is used for [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation):

> The parent / child relationship is defined implicitly by the elements' indices in the array.

If serialisation happens in a string data type that implicitly has a length attribute, then that's it. If there is no such meta data, then you need to prefix the value of  in the serialisation, reserving a predefined number of bits for it. Alternatively, if there is a special value of  bits that will never occur as actual node value, you could append it as a terminator (much like `\0` in C-strings).